# Is it possible to query Outlook 2007 using ODBC or similar?

Tags: sql, outlook, odbc, outlook-2007

I would like to query my local Outlook 2007 instance (not the server) using SQL.

- Is it possible to connect to Outlook 2007 using ODBC or similar?
- If so, what does the connection string look like?

Answer (score 1):

The only method for accessing Outlook data via some sort of database access protocol is directly within Microsoft Access. It natively supports creating a linked table (or importing into a table) from an Outlook folder in the default Outlook profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Outlook ODBC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OutlookODBC.OutlookODBC&ssr=false#overview)

1. Easy to use
2. Works with any path in Outlook, including Public Folders
3. Works with Custom Fields.
4. Set your own name for the ODBC name.
5. Works on all folders in the Outlook folder path.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OutlookODBC.OutlookODBC&ssr=false#overview